# SimpleXMLElement Access elements with namespace?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xml-namespaces

I have the following XML:

```
<ns1:getBannerLinksResponse xmlns:ns1="http://endpoint.website.com/">
    <ns1:return>
        <ns1:campaignID>0</ns1:campaignID>
        <ns1:categoryID>200230455</ns1:categoryID>
        <ns1:categoryName>Promotion</ns1:categoryName>
        <ns1:linkID>10001599</ns1:linkID>
        <ns1:linkName>KFL-20% off No Min</ns1:linkName>
        <ns1:mid>3071</ns1:mid>
        <ns1:nid>1</ns1:nid>
        <ns1:clickURL>
            http://someurl
        </ns1:clickURL>
        <ns1:endDate>Oct 15, 2012</ns1:endDate>
        <ns1:height>250</ns1:height>
        <ns1:iconURL>
            http://someurl
        </ns1:iconURL>
        <ns1:imgURL>
            http://someurl
        </ns1:imgURL>
        <ns1:landURL>
            http://someurl
        </ns1:landURL>
        <ns1:serverType>22</ns1:serverType>
        <ns1:showURL>
            http://someurl
        </ns1:showURL>
        <ns1:size>13</ns1:size>
        <ns1:startDate>Oct 14, 2012</ns1:startDate>
        <ns1:width>300</ns1:width>
    </ns1:return>
</ns1:getBannerLinksResponse>
```

I tried the following with no luck:

```
$data = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$data->registerXPathNamespace('ns1','http://endpoint.website.com/');
foreach($data->xpath('//ns1:return') as $banner)
{
  $banner->registerXPathNamespace('ns1','http://endpoint.website.com/');
  var_dump($banner);
}
```

Comment: I want to parse the return item into an array like SimpleXMLElement usually does when namespaces aren't involved.

Comment: ah ok, are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Just empty objects: `object(SimpleXMLElement)#83 (0) { }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is

```
$data = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$data->registerXPathNamespace('ns1','http://endpoint.websitecom/');
$part = $data->xpath("//ns1:return");
var_dump($part[0]->children("ns1",true));
```

Output

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]
  public 'campaignID' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'categoryID' => string '200230455' (length=9)
  public 'categoryName' => string 'Promotion' (length=9)
  public 'linkID' => string '10001599' (length=8)
  public 'linkName' => string 'KFL-20% off No Min' (length=18)
  public 'mid' => string '3071' (length=4)
  public 'nid' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'clickURL' => string '
            http://someurl
        ' (length=36)
  public 'endDate' => string 'Oct 15, 2012' (length=12)
  public 'height' => string '250' (length=3)
  public 'iconURL' => string '
            http://someurl
        ' (length=36)
  public 'imgURL' => string '
            http://someurl
        ' (length=36)
  public 'landURL' => string '
            http://someurl
        ' (length=36)
  public 'serverType' => string '22' (length=2)
  public 'showURL' => string '
            http://someurl
        ' (length=36)
  public 'size' => string '13' (length=2)
  public 'startDate' => string 'Oct 14, 2012' (length=12)
  public 'width' => string '300' (length=3)
```

Comment: man... sure have to jump through some hoops there. Seems pretty ridiculous considering you just have to do `new SimpleXMLElement($xml)` for a non-namespaced XML string. Are there any other better XML parsers for PHP out there?

Comment: Working with namespaces has not been fun since they don't have a general format .....

Comment: The complexity here comes from attempting to use XPath with namespaces, and not understanding SimpleXML functionality. I'm also not sure what you mean by namespaces "not having a general format" - AFAIK, every namespace has a full name (URI) and an arbitrary alias which is local to a particular document.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `->children()` method. If you avoid XPath and just use the SimpleXML operators, your code will end up much simpler.

Namespaced elements are also one of many things not visible when using standard PHP debug functions to debug the rather magical SimpleXML objects. (The below uses [my [`simplexml_dump()` function](https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug) instead.)

```
$data = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$banner = $data->children('ns1', true)->return; 
// Or to avoid relying on the 'ns1' alias: ->children('http://endpoint.website.com/', false);
simplexml_dump($banner);
```

Note that the 'ns1' namespace remains selected until another `->children()` call:

```
// Remember to cast to string if you want the content of an element or attribute
var_dump( (string)$banner->linkName );
```

If `<return>` can occur multiple times, this obviously becomes:

```
foreach ( $data->children('ns1', true)->return as $banner )
{
    simplexml_dump($banner);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested this is how I worked with this

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
$nameSpaces = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
foreach ($nameSpaces as $prefix => $nameSpace) {
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace($prefix, $nameSpace);
}
$results = $xml->xpath('//NameSpace:Element');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

> I want to parse the return item into an array like `SimpleXMLElement` usually does when namespaces aren't involved.

I spent several hours today trying to work out why `simplexml_load_string($xml)` refused to work with my `XML` string

Whatever I tried, the function consistently returned an empty `object`.

I didn't realise that the issue was **namespaces**.

As such, almost by accident (while idly wondering if the `:` character was problematic for the parser) I experimented with:

```
$xml = str_replace(':', '____');
```

It works.

Once you eradicate all the colons, suddenly, *namespaces are no longer involved*.

(Or, at least, what the XML Parser *recognises* as namespaces - because *we* know that `____` still represents a namespace.)

Consequently you can run the following:

```
$xml_String = str_replace(':', '____', $xml_String);
$xml_Object = simplexml_load_string($xml_String);
$xml_JSON = json_encode($xml_Object);
$xml_JSON = str_replace('____', ':', $xml_JSON);
$xml_Object = json_decode($XML_SOAP_Response_JSON, TRUE);

echo print_r($xml_Object);
```

This will:

1. remove all Namespaces
2. convert the XML into an Object
3. convert the Object into JSON
4. replace the Namespaces
5. convert the JSON back into an Object