# Pass Values into PHP variables from XML name space using SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, var-dump

I have XML content using SimpleXMLElement and var_dump results are appeared.

Sample Code:

```
$data = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$data->registerXPathNamespace('ns','http://endpoint.websitecom/');
$part = $data->xpath("//ns:return");
var_dump($part[0]->children("ns",true));
```

My Results:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[4]
  public 'result' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
      public 'result' => 
      object(SimpleXMLElement)[10]
      public 'Code' => string '0' (length=1)

  public 'amount' => string '2020.03' (length=7)
  public 'code2' => string '3934.8' (length=6)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[8]
```

How Can I pass amount, code2 variables into PHP variables or array?

```
$amount = ?????

$code2 = ????
```

Comment: Could you add the xml structure? I'm not sure if I got it correctly.

Comment: Never ever duplicate your own question only because you don't got any answer so far. It only will get you downvotes and you will loose potential friends.

Comment: Quiet many dubicates I did not note it. I found two yet. @hakre

Comment: duplicate material: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865858/simplexmlelement-access-elements-with-namespace - also self-duplicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a test case with the flowing xml code (reverse engineered on your var_dump):

```
<unknown xmlns:ns="http://endpoint.websitecom/">
 <ns:return>
  <ns:result>
   <ns:result>
    <ns:Code>0</ns:Code>
   </ns:result>
  </ns:result>
  <ns:amount>2020.03</ns:amount>
  <ns:code2>3934.8</ns:code2>
 </ns:return>
</unknown>
```

I wrote this code here for getting `$amount` and `$code2`:

```
$data = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$data->registerXPathNamespace('ns','http://endpoint.websitecom/');
$part = $data->xpath("//ns:return");
$branch=$part[0]->children("ns",true);
var_dump($branch); // your current output

$amount=$branch->amount;
$code2 =$branch->code2;
```