# Using xpath the right way, with foreach function?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xpath, opendata

I have trouble to parse from xml (external url) file to php. Idea what I am trying to accomplish is that my .php script loads url and takes specific data from it -> parse them as variables and then use those variables to post them to my database (MySQL).

My problem (might be mistaken, because new with handling XML-data and pretty new with PHP) is with "foreach" loop. When I open my script it returns following data for me:

```
1
Array
Array
Array
2
Array
Array
Array
3
```

In final version of course (when I get this working), there isn't a point for me to print/echo those values, because those variables will be posted to my database. So that in mind I am doing this right now understand about the code and where the problem might rest.

```
$url = 'http://opendata.fmi.fi/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=getFeature&storedquery_id=fmi::observations::weather::daily::simple&place=tammela&starttime='.$first_image_date.'T00:00:00Z&endtime='.$last_image_date.'T01:00:00Z&parameters=tmin,tday,tmax&';

Original xml url = http://opendata.fmi.fi/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=getFeature&storedquery_id=fmi::observations::weather::daily::simple&place=tammela&starttime=2020-05-24T00:00:00Z&endtime=2020-05-31T01:00:00Z&parameters=tmin,tday,tmax&
```

The following variable is where I take the XML-data from. Only thing which changes (whenever php is going to be used) are **$first_image_date** and **$last_image_date**. So basic idea is that I have images on my server and right now I have 9 different of images (all of them are .jpg format) and .php code takes dates from those images and matches with XML-data.

If new images get uploaded/transfered to my server, it means same time that **$url** variable will fetch data with updated date linked to the url.

```
<?php

$folder_location = "AarniAnsa/*/*/";
$jpg = glob("" . $folder_location . "*.jpg");

$first_image = reset($jpg);
$last_image = end($jpg);

ob_start();
print end(explode('@',$first_image,-2));
$first_image_date = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

ob_start();
print end(explode('@',$last_image,-2));
$last_image_date = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

define('DB_SERVER', '***');
define('DB_USERNAME', '***');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '***');
define('DB_NAME', '***');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if($link === false) {
  die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Alla oleva linkki antaa pelkästään meille tmin (Alin lämpötila), tday (Keskilämpötila) sekä tmax (Ylin lämpötila) arvot. Muita muuttujia emme tarvitse.
$url = 'http://opendata.fmi.fi/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=getFeature&storedquery_id=fmi::observations::weather::daily::simple&place=tammela&starttime='.$first_image_date.'T00:00:00Z&endtime='.$last_image_date.'T01:00:00Z&parameters=tmin,tday,tmax&';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$xmlID = 0;

$xml->registerXPathNamespace('wfs', 'http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('BsWfs', 'http://xml.fmi.fi/schema/wfs/2.0');

foreach ($xml->xpath('//wfs:member/BsWfs:BsWfsElement') as $xmlData) {
  $xmlID++;
  echo $xmlID;
  echo "<br>";
  $xmlDate = $xmlData->xpath('BsWfs:Time');
  echo $xmlDate;
  echo "<br>";
  $xmlName = $xmlData->xpath('BsWfs:ParameterName');
  echo $xmlName;
  echo "<br>";
  $xmlValue = $xmlData->xpath('BsWfs:ParameterValue');
  echo $xmlValue;
  echo "<br>";


  $query = "INSERT INTO Kaavio(ID,Päivämäärä,Parametri,Arvo) VALUES ('" . $xmlID . "','" . $xmlDate . "','" . $xmlName . "','" . $xmlValue . "')";

  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
}

 ?>
```

Now I am using "xpath", is because to my understanding (what I have learned so far) is that if I use SimpleXML option, it doesn't like data which has "prefixes". And this XML-data containes on every element some of the "prefix" tags. Thats why I was using "registerXPathNamespace" function, but hasn't solved my problem yet.

If you are wondering why I am using following code, is because all of my images format goes like this: @AnsaID-20@2020-05-31@19:55:36@.jpg :)

```
ob_start();
print end(explode('@',$first_image,-2));
$first_image_date = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Thanks for the help in advance! <3

**Edit1 (for XML-data, even though there was link for it):**

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:BsWfs="http://xml.fmi.fi/schema/wfs/2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" timeStamp="2020-06-24T20:12:30Z" numberReturned="24" numberMatched="24" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd http://xml.fmi.fi/schema/wfs/2.0 http://xml.fmi.fi/schema/wfs/2.0/fmi_wfs_simplefeature.xsd">
<wfs:member>
<BsWfs:BsWfsElement gml:id="BsWfsElement.1.1.1">
<BsWfs:Location>
<gml:Point gml:id="BsWfsElementP.1.1.1" srsDimension="2" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4258">
<gml:pos>60.81401 23.49761 </gml:pos>
</gml:Point>
</BsWfs:Location>
<BsWfs:Time>2020-05-24T00:00:00Z</BsWfs:Time>
<BsWfs:ParameterName>tmin</BsWfs:ParameterName>
<BsWfs:ParameterValue>8.2</BsWfs:ParameterValue>
</BsWfs:BsWfsElement>
</wfs:member>
<wfs:member>
<BsWfs:BsWfsElement gml:id="BsWfsElement.1.1.2">
<BsWfs:Location>
<gml:Point gml:id="BsWfsElementP.1.1.2" srsDimension="2" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4258">
<gml:pos>60.81401 23.49761 </gml:pos>
</gml:Point>
</BsWfs:Location>
<BsWfs:Time>2020-05-24T00:00:00Z</BsWfs:Time>
<BsWfs:ParameterName>tday</BsWfs:ParameterName>
<BsWfs:ParameterValue>11.1</BsWfs:ParameterValue>
</BsWfs:BsWfsElement>
</wfs:member>
<wfs:member>
<BsWfs:BsWfsElement gml:id="BsWfsElement.1.1.3">
<BsWfs:Location>
<gml:Point gml:id="BsWfsElementP.1.1.3" srsDimension="2" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4258">
<gml:pos>60.81401 23.49761 </gml:pos>
</gml:Point>
</BsWfs:Location>
<BsWfs:Time>2020-05-24T00:00:00Z</BsWfs:Time>
<BsWfs:ParameterName>tmax</BsWfs:ParameterName>
<BsWfs:ParameterValue>14.3</BsWfs:ParameterValue>
</BsWfs:BsWfsElement>
</wfs:member>
```

**Edit2 (adding now "partially working" code, but with a MySQL problem)**

```
<?php

$folder_location = "AarniAnsa/*/*/";
$jpg = glob("" . $folder_location . "*.jpg");

$first_image = reset($jpg);
$last_image = end($jpg);

ob_start();
print end(explode('@',$first_image,-2));
$first_image_date = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

ob_start();
print end(explode('@',$last_image,-2));
$last_image_date = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

define('DB_SERVER', '***');
define('DB_USERNAME', '***');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '***');
define('DB_NAME', '***');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if($link === false) {
  die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Alla oleva linkki antaa pelkästään meille tmin (Alin lämpötila), tday (Keskilämpötila) sekä tmax (Ylin lämpötila) arvot. Muita muuttujia emme tarvitse.
$url = 'http://opendata.fmi.fi/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=getFeature&storedquery_id=fmi::observations::weather::daily::simple&place=tammela&starttime='.$first_image_date.'T00:00:00Z&endtime='.$last_image_date.'T01:00:00Z&parameters=tmin,tday,tmax&';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$xmlID = 0;

$xml->registerXPathNamespace('wfs', 'http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('BsWfs', 'http://xml.fmi.fi/schema/wfs/2.0');

foreach ($xml->xpath('//wfs:member/BsWfs:BsWfsElement') as $xmlData) {
  $xmlID++;
  echo $xmlID;
  echo "<br>";
  $xmlDate = (string)$xmlData->xpath('BsWfs:Time')[0];
  echo $xmlDate;
  echo "<br>";
  $xmlName = (string)$xmlData->xpath('BsWfs:ParameterName')[0];
  echo $xmlName;
  echo "<br>";
  $xmlValue = (string)$xmlData->xpath('BsWfs:ParameterValue')[0];
  echo $xmlValue;
  echo "<br>";

  $sql = "INSERT INTO Kaavio(Päivämäärä, Parametri, Arvo) VALUES('$xmlDate', '$xmlName', '$xmlValue')";
  mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));

}

 ?>
```

Following code is making this error and I have checked that database settings are right 100% so problem can't be with that and also I have tried to replace php variables with normal text (such as 'testi' or 'aarni') and that didn't worked either.

```
1
2020-05-24T00:00:00Z
tmin
8.2
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '�ivämäärä, Parametri, Arvo) VALUES('2020-05-24T00:00:00Z', 'tmin...' at line 1
```

**Edit3 (fixed all the problems I had previously and adding the whole code here, so in future if someone has similar problem they can just copy/paste it)**

```
<?php

$folder_location = "AarniAnsa/*/*/";
$jpg = glob("" . $folder_location . "*.jpg");

$first_image = reset($jpg);
$last_image = end($jpg);

ob_start();
print end(explode('@',$first_image,-2));
$first_image_date = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

ob_start();
print end(explode('@',$last_image,-2));
$last_image_date = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

define('DB_SERVER', '***');
define('DB_USERNAME', '***');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '***');
define('DB_NAME', '***');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if($link === false) {
  die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Alla oleva linkki antaa pelkästään meille tmin (Alin lämpötila), tday (Keskilämpötila) sekä tmax (Ylin lämpötila) arvot. Muita muuttujia emme tarvitse.
$url = 'http://opendata.fmi.fi/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=getFeature&storedquery_id=fmi::observations::weather::daily::simple&place=tammela&starttime='.$first_image_date.'T00:00:00Z&endtime='.$last_image_date.'T01:00:00Z&parameters=tmin,tday,tmax&';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$xml->registerXPathNamespace('wfs', 'http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('BsWfs', 'http://xml.fmi.fi/schema/wfs/2.0');

foreach ($xml->xpath('//wfs:member/BsWfs:BsWfsElement') as $xmlData) {
  $xmlDate = (string)$xmlData->xpath('BsWfs:Time')[0];
  $xmlDate = substr($xmlDate,0,10);
  echo $xmlDate;
  echo "<br>";
  $xmlName = (string)$xmlData->xpath('BsWfs:ParameterName')[0];
  echo $xmlName;
  echo "<br>";
  $xmlValue = (string)$xmlData->xpath('BsWfs:ParameterValue')[0];
  echo $xmlValue;
  echo "<br>";

  $sql = "INSERT INTO `Kaavio` (`date`, `parameter`, `value`) VALUES('$xmlDate', '$xmlName', '$xmlValue')";
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
}

 ?>
```

This is now, how my array is looking/showing when I open my .php script:

```
2020-05-24
tmin
8.2
2020-05-24
tday
11.1
2020-05-24
tmax
14.3
2020-05-25
tmin
8.0
2020-05-25
tday
13.0
2020-05-25
tmax
18.2
2020-05-26
tmin
4.6
2020-05-26
tday
14.9
```

And this is how my phpMyAdmin looks (using MariaDB):

[XML Data parsed to my database :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgma1.png)

Comment: SimpleXML has no problems with namespaces (prefixes), it's more that people don't understand how to use them.  Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865858/simplexmlelement-access-elements-with-namespace and see if this helps.  If not, can you add some sample XML and I'm sure someone will give a more specific answer.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. I'll check it out and edited my post for XML-data.

Comment: The code to fetch the individual values will give you *array to string* conversion errors as `xpath()` always returns a list of elements.  Also these will be SimpleXMLElements so should be converted to strings to ensure they don't cause further problems.  So something like `(string)$xmlData->xpath('BsWfs:Time')[0]` should give you the results.  BTW *even though there was link for it* - not everyone wants to visit links posted to SO and in future these links may stop working, so sample data is needed in the question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll try it today. Didn't wanted to be rude with my "edit post".

Comment: Sorry @NigelRen for late reply, got it working now (partially) getting values, but next problem (which I suspected that is going to happen) is that I am unable to transfer those values to my database. Getting following error (check my post, going to edit)

Comment: I think this is due to the character set you are using for field names, try using backticks round the names (`\`Päivämäärä\``).  You should also ask a new question as this is a different issue to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to register the namespace on any element you call the xpath() method on. In you case you should to register the `http://xml.fmi.fi/schema/wfs/2.0` on the `$xmlData` variable inside the loop.

Additionally SimpleXMLElement::xpath() return an array of SimpleXMLElement instance. To fetch a single value reference the first element and cast it:

```
$xmlDate = (string)$xmlData->xpath('BsWfs:Time')[0];
```

Only `DOMxpath::evaluate()` is able to return scalar values directly. The type cast is part of the expression. Here is an example:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML(getXMLString());
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('wfs', 'http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0');
$xpath->registerNamespace('BsWfs', 'http://xml.fmi.fi/schema/wfs/2.0');

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//wfs:member/BsWfs:BsWfsElement') as $index => $element) {
    var_dump(
        [
             'id' => $index + 1,
             'date' => $xpath->evaluate('string(BsWfs:Time)', $element),
             'name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(BsWfs:ParameterName)', $element),
             'value' => $xpath->evaluate('number(BsWfs:ParameterValue)', $element)
        ]
    );
}
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["date"]=>
  string(20) "2020-05-24T00:00:00Z"
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "tmin"
  ["value"]=>
  float(8.2)
}
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(2)
  ["date"]=>
  string(20) "2020-05-24T00:00:00Z"
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "tday"
  ["value"]=>
  float(11.1)
}
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(3)
  ["date"]=>
  string(20) "2020-05-24T00:00:00Z"
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "tmax"
  ["value"]=>
  float(14.3)
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I have tried earlier with @NigelRen comment and it got working partially (my code prints values, but only first column/element, after that I get error with MySQL). Having trouble to insert values from "foreach" loop to database. If you have time, check my orinal post, have added the "partially" working code with the error.

Comment: In this case you don't need to register the namespace inside the loop, try running the code in OP's question to check.

Comment: Not because it was already registered, but because the automatic registration for context namespaces. Might work but is really fragile.

Comment: TBH I think using XPath in these sorts of cases is a waste of resources anyway, it's easy enough to get the values without it (that is the final elements).

Comment: Added on original post working code, which does exactly what I wanted. Happy with the results and thank you for your help <3